# Nested for loop in a batch file does not expand

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

First time here and keen to ask for assistance for something that has trapped me for my entire day.

I am have a root directory containing subfolders to 44 countries. Inside the country sub-folders are files which I would like to add in a zip archive to be saved in the same country sub-folder.

I have a list file `cou_dir_list.lst` that contains the following entry:

```
Z:\Data\Fossil-Fuel Subsidies Report\common data files\AUS
Z:\Data\Fossil-Fuel Subsidies Report\common data files\AUT
Z:\Data\Fossil-Fuel Subsidies Report\common data files\ZAF
```

For the sake of simplicity, I only listed down 3 countries.

I have the following code:

```
REM @Echo On
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%f in (cou_dir_list.lst) do (

    for /D %%g in ("%%f\*???_*.*") do (
        "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%f\XXX_deleg.zip" "%%g"
    )

)
```

The idea is to get each country sub-directory (by reading through lst file) then adding each file (with format `*???_*.*`) inside the country folder into a `XXX_deleg.zip` archive to be saved in the same country folder pointed to by `%%f`.

However, I am still getting the following `echo`s:

```
Z:\Data\Fossil-Fuel Subsidies Report\common data files>REM @Echo On

Z:\Data\Fossil-Fuel Subsidies Report\common data files>setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Z:\Data\Fossil-Fuel Subsidies Report\common data files>for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %f in (cou_dir_list.lst) do (for / %g in ("%f\*???_*.*") do ("c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%f\XXX_deleg.zip" "%g" ) )

Z:\Data\Fossil-Fuel Subsidies Report\common data files>(for / %g in ("Z:\Data\Fossil-Fuel Subsidies Report\common data files\AUS\*???_*.*") do ("c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "Z:\Data\Fossil-Fuel Subsidies Report\common data files\AUS\XXX_deleg.zip" "%g" ) )

Z:\Data\Fossil-Fuel Subsidies Report\common data files>(for / %g in ("Z:\Data\Fossil-Fuel Subsidies Report\common data files\AUT\*???_*.*") do ("c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "Z:\Data\Fossil-Fuel Subsidies Report\common data files\AUT\XXX_deleg.zip" "%g" ) )
```

It seems that the variables in the second for loop are not being expanded as they are being printed out as `%g`.

Comment: Does `Z:\Data\Fossil-Fuel Subsidies Report\common data files\AUT\XXX_deleg.zip` end up containing the correct data?

Comment: The `FOR /D` command is trying to find `FOLDERS`.  Not files.  You need to remove the `/D`.

Comment: @melpomene No zip file gets generated as the commands on the second for loop don't even get executed.

Comment: @Squashman Many thanks, that really did work!

Comment: Consider reading the help file for the command you are trying to use before asking a question.  At a command prompt type: `for /?`.  The help for the `/D` option clearly states, **If set contains wildcards, then specifies to match against directory names instead of file names.**

Comment: Why does one of the items in your file list have a leading colon, **`:`**? Also we need to see a relevant example structure of perhaps `Z:\Data\Fossil-Fuel Subsidies Report\common data files\AUS\ ` so that we can be sure of which directories you're trying to parse with respect to this `*???_*.*`.

Comment: For the code at hand you do not need to enable delayed expansion, so I'd remove `EnableDelayedExpansion` in order not to have trouble with exclamation marks (in case there are any in your file paths)...

Comment: Instead of `XXX_deleg.zip` would you prefer to call it `AUS_deleg.zip` etc? (where XXX is each country)? If so, then use `"%%f\%%~nf_deleg.zip"`.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou indeed, many thanks!